# My Blazor web app is giving me this error when I try to view a page

Tags: error-handling, runtime-error, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazorstrap

I do not know what the below error is trying to tell me...
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at GSG.WebApp.Client.Pages.Index.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder) in C:\Users\ZachKoman\internalhrtool\GSG.WebApp\Client\Pages\Index.razor:line 0
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)

The error began when I tried testing these filter input boxes.

```
    <!--Input fields for filtering-->
<div style="display:flex">
    <div class="filter">
        <BSLabel style="width=20%">Lastname: </BSLabel >
        <BSInput InputType="InputType.Text" placeholder="name" @bind-Value="lastname" />
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
        <BSLabel style="width=20%">Company: </BSLabel>
        <BSInput InputType="InputType.Text" placeholder="Company" @bind-Value="company"/>
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
        <BSLabel style="width=20%">Skill: </BSLabel>
        <BSInput InputType="InputType.Text" placeholder="Skill" @bind-Value="skill[0]"/>
    </div>
        @for (int i = 1; i < skillFilterStatus; i++)
        {
            <div class="filter">
                <BSLabel style="width=20%">Skill: </BSLabel>
                <BSInput InputType="InputType.Text" placeholder="Skill" @bind-Value="skill[i]"/>
            </div>
        }
        @if(skillFilterStatus != 0)
        {
                <div class="filterBttn">
                <BSButton style="background-color: #ed1c24;" @onclick="FilterMinus"><i class="oi oi-minus" style="color: white" ></i></BSButton>
            </div>        
        }
        @if(skillFilterStatus < 2)
        {
            <div class="filterBttn">
                <BSButton style="background-color: #8522e4;" @onclick="FilterClick"><i class="oi oi-plus" style="color: white" ></i></BSButton>
            </div>
        }
    <div class="filterBttn">
        <BSButton @onclick="ApplyFilter" style="background-color: #8522e4; color: white">Apply</BSButton>
    </div>
</div>
@code
    private int skillFilterStatus = 0;
        private string lastname;
        private string company;
        private string[] skill;
        private void ApplyFilter(){
 
        Console.WriteLine(lastname+"-"+company+"-"+skill[0]+"-"+skill[1]+"-"+skill[2]);

    }
```

Comment: Did you really give us your code? `skill` is not set, only defined (would cause an Exception when you try to access `skill[0]`). You did not define/show definition of the two methods `FilterMinus` and `FilterClick`. Where are the `{}` of `@code`?

Comment: I left a few things out because they weren't necessary but I will try defining skill.